# select proper firefox version in selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium with java (Eclipse Oxygen).
I have installed Firefox 56 (old version to run firebug and firepath addon) along with Firefox Developer Edition.
By default, webdriver launches Firefox 56. I want to launch Firefox Developer Edition by webdriver. So how can I set/change the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by specifying the path to the executable of the Firefox version you want to launch in the `FirefoxOptions` which you can pass to the constructor of the `FirefoxDriver`.

For example, if you have the following code to launch the default Firefox on your machine:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();   

  driver.get("http://demo.borland.com");
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Demo Application")).click();

  driver.quit();
}
```

You can change it to to launch the Firefox Developer Edition like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
  options.setBinary(new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe")));
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);    

  driver.get("http://demo.borland.com");
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Demo Application")).click();

  driver.quit();
}
```